# Avoiding Triangulation of User Location Hacks

Tags: geolocation, triangulation

I am building a location based app where users can see distance to other users. What decimal place should I round longitude and latitude to to avoid making it possible for users to triangulate the position of other users? I am not sure what a "reasonable level of uncertainty" for other user's position is.

Comment: If you show the distance to users, how can you avoid triangulation?

Comment: Round it before I save it to the server on the original user's device! traiangulation was a vulneriability in the old version of Tinder to give an example.

Answer (score 0):

Round Long/Lat to vary degrees of decimal places to introduce error. Hundredths is a good answer, since on average long/lat lines are .69 miles apart, thus introducing an average .69x.69 square mile error.

You can also use a custom geohashing system to build your own designated shapes to lump points into. Geohashes are better near the poles because they don't risk their area going to zero as the system with long/lat does because latitude lines have a distance of close to zero near the poles, which potentially poses a security risk there for triangulation.

At the end of the day, for a consumer app that nobody is going to use at the poles, rounding seems sufficient.